# AutoMapper -- how to manipulate all values of a given type during mapping?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, automapper

Quick question regarding Automapper.

I'm mapping data from an incoming web service, where datetimes fields are not null, but sometimes have the value of DateTime.MinValue as a work-around (I don't own this service so I'm at their mercy I'm afraid).  I'm mapping from those objects to Linq To Sql objects created off of a db model I created based on the service description.

Everything is working fine, until I try to submit new rows where DateTime.MinValue is set on the datetime fields.  Of course, the solution is to replace DateTime.MinValue with SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value as Sql Server chokes on DateTime.MinValue.

I would like to do this automatically with the mapping... that is, replace this on *any* datetime fields in the incoming web service call without having to specify on a field by field basis.

Formatters won't do the trick since they only deal with string formatting, and IValueResolver doesn't appear to do what I need either.  That appears to be called once per instance of the parent type, not per field within the type  (I tried to use it with .ForAllMembers()).  Perhaps I did something wrong.

If the NullSubstitute method was generic -- that is, if the signature was something like Substitute<T, Func<T,T>>, then I think I'd be in business.

Documentation / online samples haven't provided much in the way of direction... and while I could start digging through the source, I was hoping someone with more in-depth knowledge of the system could comment (Jimmy?).

I would assume that something like this *should* be a feature somewhere, but then again, there may be other issues at play which complicate implementing something like this.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would [TypeConverter](http://github.com/jbogard/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapperSamples/GlobalTypeConverters.cs) help?

Comment: Yeah, looks like it would -- don't know how I missed that one!  Thanks for the heads up.  Will vote this as soon as I can implement / ensure it's doing what I need (which I believe it will).

Comment: I haven't tried it and I confess - I didn't get every detail of Your question, hence - I'm unsure. Anyway - always try to check source code of tools You are using. :)